# how to update product information outside from Magento

Tags: php, magento2

I want to programmatically update product information, such as quantity, price, etc.
(from outside of the Magento source directory.)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento is pretty easy to bootstrap. If you want a standalone script where you can access all your functions, just add the following at the top of your PHP file :

```
define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once MAGENTO . '/../app/Mage.php'; //or whatever location your Mage.php file is
Mage::app(Mage_Core_Model_Store::ADMIN_CODE); //initialization with another store is possible
```

After that you can load all your models. To update your products I suggest you two ways. The regular one :

```php
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($myStoreId)->load($myProductId)
    ->setPrice(50)
    ->save();
```

Or the API model usage :

```
$api = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_api_v2');
$api->update($productId, $productData, $store, $identifierType);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend leveraging the REST APIs available in M2x to Create/Update products and its attributes.

*Note:* You have the option of using OAuth or Bearer Tokens in Magento 2 to Authenticate/Authorize your API invocations.

You can find additional information on all the APIs available in Magento 2.1 here -
 http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_21.html

You'll find specifics of the APIs you need under the grouping titled `catalogProductRepositoryV1`

- Get info on product(s) using a search/filter criteria -> `GET /V1/products`
- Get info on a specific Product -> `GET /V1/products/{sku}`
- Create New Product -> `POST /V1/products`
- Create/Update specific Product -> `PUT /V1/products/{sku}`

I haven't tested the code, but I think something like this should do the trick:

```
    $BEARER_TOKEN_TO_USE_FOR_TRANSACTION = 'XYZ';

    $REQUEST_HEADER = array( 
                        "Authorization => Bearer ". $BEARER_TOKEN_TO_USE_FOR_TRANSACTION , 
                        "cache-control: no-cache",
                        "content-type: application/json"
                        ); 
    $REQUEST_URL='INSTANCE_URL/rest/V1/products';

    $PRODUCT_DATA_TO_USE ='{
      "product": {
        ENTER_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES_AS_JSON
    } }';

    $CURL_OBJ = curl_init($REQUEST_URL); 

    $CURL_OPTIONS_ARRAY_TO_USE = array (
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $REQUEST_HEADER,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $PRODUCT_DATA_TO_USE,
        CURLOPT_URL => $REQUEST_URL,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    );

    curl_setopt_array($CURL_OBJ, $CURL_OPTIONS_ARRAY_TO_USE);
    $result = curl_exec($CURL_OBJ);
    $result =  json_decode($result);
    echo 'Output -> " . $result;
```